# Llamar a archivo js que contiene variable java, desde html5

Tags: javascript, java

Tengo una funcion JS embebida en mi pagina web, al final de body

```
<script>
function permisosMenu() {
  var cadena = <%=permisos%>
  if(!cadena.includes(1) && !cadena.includes(2) && !cadena.includes(3) && !cadena.includes(4))
        document.getElementById("bloque1").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(5) && !cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) &&
          !cadena.includes(9) && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12) &&
          !cadena.includes(13) && !cadena.includes(14) && !cadena.includes(15) && !cadena.includes(16))
        document.getElementById("bloque2").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) && !cadena.includes(9) 
          && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12))
        document.getElementById("bloque2_op2").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(17) && !cadena.includes(18) && !cadena.includes(19) && !cadena.includes(20) )
        document.getElementById("bloque3").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(21) && !cadena.includes(22) && !cadena.includes(23))
        document.getElementById("bloque4").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(24) && !cadena.includes(25))
        document.getElementById("bloque5").style.display ="none";

  for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
      if(!cadena.includes(i)){
        document.getElementById("op"+i).style.display ="none";
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Este codigo cumple con lo que necesito, la variable cadena obtendrá su valor de <%=permisos%>(el cual se encuentra al inicio del documento antes del body)

```
<%
String permisos= (String)session.getAttribute("permisos");
%>
```

Cuando esta directamente puesto en el html funciona correctamente, cuando lo quiero poner en un archivo .js aparte, para luego llamarlo con

```
<script source="ruta.."></script>
```

no me funciona, acaso el scriplest <%=permisos> es lo que no permite llamarlo en mi htlm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así es, el archivo js lo incluirá en el navegador (dejando el entorno de servidor de java) por lo que no podrías sacar funciones de java fuera del contexto jsp, lo que te recomiendo es guarda tus permisos en un input hidden y leelo desde javascript, o simplemente haz una llamada ajax a un jsp que te devuelva un json con los permisos que tengas.

quedando algo así en el body

```
<input id="permisos" type="hidden" value="<%=permisos%>">
```

y en Javascript usando jquery

```
var cadena = $('#permisos').val();
```

Comment: ingeniosa y elegante forma de resolverlo, quería evitar el ajax y json porque  todavia no domino esos temas, gracias por tu aporte